# Under what conditions does "select non-manifold not show up in the select menu?

Tags: selection-tools

I use blender to create designs for 3d printing.   I use select non-manifold a lot to look for problems as I work on a design.   I see that sometimes select non-manifld doesn't show up in the select menu.

I don't know if it's just for the more complicated designs or not, so I'm wondering if anyone knows under what conditions select non-manifold is not available.

Answer (score 1):

You must be in vertex-edit mode in order to have that option.

Edit: orrrr edge-edit mode, confirmed.

Comment: It also works in edge mode. as stated in the other answer it is now under the  "Select all by trait" menu and will only show up if you are currently in Edge or Vertex selection mode

Comment: yes.   I recently switched to the latest version.  I think a combination of not always being in the right edit mode (under the old version) and the new version moving it cause my confusion.

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of Blender moved "select non-maifold" to a sub-menu under "Select All by Trait"